# Getting text from angular element with no text value

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium

I've bumped into a text field in a simple table where the text I want to check/extract is not part of any value in the element.

Using Python and Selenium I was trying to get the value by using `get_value`, `get_text` or `get_attribute` but with no success. Everything returns

> AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_text'

which is not surprising as there is no real value in the element. It's an AngularJS based website.

The element looks like this and the text inside is "France":

```
<span class="keyword-autocomplete-container" model="flavor.subregion" keyword-autocomplete="subregion" filter="{ancestorId: flavor.regionId || flavor.countryId}" with-aliases="true" replace-alias="true">  <input ng-model="localModel" ng-disabled="ngDisabled" mass-autocomplete-item="createOptions()" ng-keypress="onKeyPressed($event)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" autocomplete="off"></span>
```

with this children:

```
    <input ng-model="localModel" ng-disabled="ngDisabled" mass-   autocomplete-item="createOptions()" ng-keypress="onKeyPressed($event)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" autocomplete="off">
```

The selector I have pointed to that element works fine. I can type some text or click it with no issues. Anyone can help how to read a text from such element? Thank you.

Comment: try using javascript input.value where input is your element..

Comment: Where exactly is the text `France` displayed?

Comment: Thanks I'll try the JS. @nullpointer the "France" is displayed on the page in that input field but you can't find it in DOM at all. It's somehow served by the JS but I don't have any idea how to catch it.

Comment: Update: `self.element.get_attribute('value')`  finally worked so I'm sorry for a hoax. Will be more careful before raising a question next time. Thank you guys for quick answer anyway!